# shared_ptr based design issues

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I use shared_ptr in my application design, and I have tendency that more and more objects become heap-allocated instead of to be a simple objects on stack (or agregates of more complex objects).
Instead of simple (but with risk that Foo::bar will become dangling reference in more complex situation) ...

`struct Bar { };
struct Foo { Foo(Bar& bar) : bar(bar) { }; Bar& bar; };
int main() {
  Bar bar;
  Foo foo(bar);
  // ...
}`

... I need to do ...

`struct Bar { };
struct Foo { Foo(shared_ptr bar) : bar(bar) { }; shared_ptr<Bar> bar; };
int main() {
  shared_ptr<Bar> bar = make_shared<Bar>();
  Foo foo(bar);
  // ...
}`

... because I want to avoid of manual objects life-time tracking
Did I missed point in shared_ptr usage or this is pay for automatic life-time management ? Or maybe this is bad design sign ?

Comment: `shared_ptr` should be used sparingly. The life-cycle of a given object is an integral part of the functional behavior. If you don't have a clear specification of the behavior, you won't get anywhere... and if you do, then you don't need to use `shared_ptr` everywhere. It's no panacea, or silver bullet, and at one point you'll realize that you're leaking memory like crazy because you have cycles of references, and no idea where to start because your collaboration diagram is a mess :/

Comment: What is your point?  You wanted to work with shared_ptr and now you are.  Since main() is an owner, he should have a shared_ptr.  Using shared_ptr is more verbuous than using references.

Comment: @Matthieu: when considering owners (shared_ptr) and users (weak_ptr) and using a layered approach, shared_ptr can really help you.  With no design you're just replacing possible dangling pointers with possible memory leaks

Comment: @Matthieu life-cycle - yes, but not life time I think, because it depends on outer object (agregator). Am I missing something ?

Comment: @stefaanv So Foo should have weak_ptr to Bar, because it just observes value, not owns ? When object are owner and when are not ?

Comment: @stefanv Should I avoid first approach because of implicitness of life time management ?

Comment: @vnw: no there's nothing wrong with the first approach.  When passing a reference, it is clear that the caller remains owner of bar, when passing a shared_ptr, both become owner, when passing an auto_ptr, the ownership would be transferred.  However, when passing a raw pointer, it must be documented who is the intended owner, because that is not clear.

Comment: @stefaanv: I think that a description of this layered approach could constitute a really helpful answer. I guess what you mean (a tree of dependencies instead of a graph), but I am afraid that most will not :)

Comment: @vnm: about weak_ptr: yes, owners must get a shared_ptr, users must get a weak_ptr and lock whenever needed.  Owners and users must be defined at design time

Comment: @Matthieu: yes a tree of dependencies would be ideal, however, within defined layers, one could be a bit more loose.

Comment: @stefaanv: yes, tree isn't actually the concept I was aiming for. A directed acyclic graph can be ensured as long as the layers are ordered and any object in a given layer can only own objects in layers strictly "higher" than its own. Observers are used to peek downward (or within the same layer). It gets tricky when managing the temporary `shared_ptr` created from those observers, a 3rd class (to prevent escape) would have been useful there.

Comment: Can you suggees some open source projects, where I can find example of good shared_ptr usage and right done life-time control ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a question of your object life cycle. You should use shared_ptr when you really share an object between multiple other objects.

In your case the owner of FOO and BAR must control the lifecycle of both. Maybe it is possible to make BAR a private member of you class FOO and let FOO control the life cycle.

I personally use the smart pointers to express the ownership of an object. Shared_ptr means that it is really shared and I am not the only owner of this object. 
Scoped or unique pointer show that I am the only owner of the object. If you want to transfer the ownership you can use auto_ptr or the C++0x move semantics.

I have seen at least in bigger projects that the lack of life cycle control will lead to dangling objects. So you don't have a direct memory leak any longer because of automatic life-time management but you get circular dependencies. Which lead to the same result.

To answer your question if this is bad design. It depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

It is a sign of bad design. `shared_ptr` exists for when your objects must be heap allocated. You should never additionally allocate anything on the heap just because you can use `shared_ptr`. The stack is still the best choice by miles.

You need to know before you start deciding how you're going to implement it, what objects need to go on the heap and which need to go on the stack, and what the ownership is. Then you can use `shared_ptr` as an implementation tool.

Comment: What if some class A controls lifefime of B, and C, controlled by someone other need pointer to B ? Should I use shared_ptr in this situation or, again, this is bad design ?

Comment: @vnm: You can force `shared_ptr` as patches to a bad design, but the real solution requires *thinking*. You need to think whether `A` is responsible of `B` and `C`, and at the same time, whether that someone else should hold a reference to `B` (seemingly an internal detail of `A`) if `A` can be destructed before that last object. In some cases you will find that `B` is not *owned* by `A`, but rather *shared* by `A` and `D`, and that is a hint that you want to convert that to a pointer (smart pointer). In other situations it will be owned by `A` and `D` might still hold a reference...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried working on values instead of pointers ?

Comment: No. I can't do this because pointee should be shared among several objects